# ¿Error al imprimir operaciones aritméticas en RUBY con PUTS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Ruby y traté de realizar un ejercicio básico con operaciones aritméticas, pero no entiendo que pasa al mostrar y realizar el cálculo de algunas operaciones dentro de un `puts`:

```
puts "Ingrese una variable para realizar la operaciones arítmeticas"
print "El primer valor númerico: "
Y = gets
print "El segundo valor: "
X = gets
puts ("Suma: "+(Y+X).to_s)
puts ("Resta: "+(Y-X).to_s)
puts ("Producto: "+(Y*X).to_s)
puts ("Cociente: "+(Y/X).to_s)
puts ("Resto: "+(Y%X).to_s)
```

En cada una de las instrucciones donde intento mostrar el resultado, aparece un error diferente para cada uno de las operaciones, a excepción de la suma y el resto (o módulo):

Para la sustracción:

```
Ingrese una variable para realizar la operaciones arítmeticas
El primer valor númerico: 4
El segundo valor: 1
Suma: 41Traceback (most recent call last):
./Ejercicio1.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined method `-' for "4":String (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  -@
```

Producto:

```
Ingrese una variable para realizar la operaciones arítmeticas
El primer valor númerico: 4
El segundo valor: 1
Suma: 41
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from ./Ejercicio1.rb:8:in `<main>'
./Ejercicio1.rb:8:in `*': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Cociente:

```
Ingrese una variable para realizar la operaciones arítmeticas
El primer valor númerico: 4
El segundo valor: 1
Suma: 41
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from ./Ejercicio1.rb:8:in `<main>'
./Ejercicio1.rb:8:in `*': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás tratando de sumar strings, para los cuales solo está definidas las operaciones [`+`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/String/%2B) y [`%`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/String/%25), el resto te va a arrojar error:

```
[60] pry(main)> x = '1'
=> "1"
[61] pry(main)> y = '2'
=> "2"
[62] pry(main)> x + y
=> "12"
[63] pry(main)> x - y
NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for "1":String
from (pry):193:in `<main>'
[64] pry(main)> x * y
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
from (pry):194:in `*'
[65] pry(main)> x / y
NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for "1":String
from (pry):195:in `<main>'
[66] pry(main)> x % y
=> "1"
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es convertir tu string a integer usando [`gets.to_i`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i)